# How to use two condition in join statement via linq?

Tags: c#, linq

I try to add two condition to my join but I can't. I use  `||` operator.

```
from pay in db.Payments
join FlyRpt in db.FlightReportTickets 
on pay.ObjectIdDepartue equals FlyRpt.DepartureId ||
   FlyRpt.DepartureId equals pay.ObjectIdReturn

join prof in db.Profiles on FlyRpt.UserId equals prof.UserId
where pay.ReserveType == 1 &&
    pay.Transactionsuccess &&
    pay.IssueDate >= fromDateTime &&
    pay.IssueDate <= toDateTime

select new
{
    FlyRpt.FullPrice
};
```

Comment: what is the error message?

Comment: Can not apply operator || to operand  of type System.Nullable<int> and System.Nullable<int>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use where if you want to implement OR in join:

```
from pay in db.Payments
from FlyRpt in db.FlightReportTickets
where pay.ObjectIdDepartue == FlyRpt.DepartureId
|| FlyRpt.DepartureId == pay.ObjectIdReturn
join prof in db.Profiles on FlyRpt.UserId equals prof.UserId
where pay.ReserveType == 1 &&
pay.Transactionsuccess &&
pay.IssueDate >= fromDateTime &&
pay.IssueDate <= toDateTime
select new
{
    FlyRpt.FullPrice,
};
```

Comment: or operation ......

Answer (score 1):

You can use cross-join because you can't use `OR` in other joins:

```
from pay in db.Payments
from FlyRpt in db.FlightReportTickets 
where 
    pay.ObjectIdDepartue = FlyRpt.DepartureId ||
    FlyRpt.DepartureId equals pay.ObjectIdReturn
join prof in db.Profiles 
on FlyRpt.UserId equals prof.UserId
where 
    pay.ReserveType == 1 &&
    pay.Transactionsuccess &&
    pay.IssueDate >= fromDateTime &&
    pay.IssueDate <= toDateTime
select new
{
    FlyRpt.FullPrice,
};
```